# Plausible? Brown Dwarfs are rogue celestial bodies because they absorb all light due to their thick layer of matte black soot

Tags: light, brown-dwarf, photons

My theory of why Brown Dwarfs are the rogue celestial bodies that travel through galaxies without a set course. My first theory would be their matte black in color due to a layer of soot.Light does not reflect off a thick layer of black powdered soot,The light is absorbed fully making it impossible to view in a color light spectrum.Second these giants are iron all the way through making its mass weight extremely dense in proportion to its volume.Third They are extremely   cold having no energy to burn,some might be completely dead giving off no heat and would be almost impossible to capture but by chance with FIR technology heating a spot up and captured with IR.These dead cold Dwarfs might even be completely stationary in a solar system having no momentum from photon light scattering.Some might have collided with a plant causing velocity momentum and set to a linear path.Some might be smoldering out still emitting some FIR radiation making a small gap to be captured by IR technology.They can travel through solar systems or galaxies as pleased with little interference of gravity from planets due to its extreme mass weight,until it transcends extremely close to an active star and slingshotted around the star,Now hot and glowing the Brown Dwarf can be seen through color spectrum and will radiate FIR.

Could this theory be plausible? If not describe with links to creditable data no pictures or diagrams.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Plausible or not?

Comment: @Gerrit-Your highly knowledgeable in absorption and how light works.I would be honerd to have your thoughts on my theory.

Comment: @Conrad Turner-These objects have not been defined or have credible data besides being viewed with Uv.I can speculate as much as the next man.Im glad my post caught your attention.It only verifies it is of importantance

Comment: *I believe different levels of light interaction on a mass causes planets to move away from stars*, your belief is factually incorrect.  The photon pressure on a planet is not  sufficient to push a heavy planet out of orbit.  Insufficient by many, *many* orders of magnitude.

Comment: @gerrit-The photon pressure only pushes objects of metallic and light color, planets with no moons are stuck in the void with little orbital movement thus being consumed by its exspanding exploding star.This pressure works slowly but surely.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is due to unclear formulation on the part of the sender rather than unclear physical understanding on the part of the receiver.

Comment: Please have a go at copy-editing your question to make it a lot clearer. For example I suspect you mean "rogue" not "rouge". Check that you are using standard punctuation and spelling. It will encourage better answers if you show that you have made an effort in asking your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a personal, non-mainstream theory.

Answer (score 2):

> They are so dark they absorb almost every bit of light from any star and receive no photon velocity momentum or electromagnetic radiation.

The momentum that a planet receives or does not receive from photons is negligible for its orbit.

> These dark masses are extremely high in mass and do not interact with light like other planets and moons.

A dark object very much interacts with light: it absorbs light.  An object that does not interact with light would be transparent, not dark.

> I believe different levels of light interaction on a mass causes planets to move away from stars or stay at bay.

Planetary orbits are governed by gravitational effects.  The effect of light interaction on orbits is negligible.

Finally, none of this has anything to do with planets in orbit or not.  Planetary orbits are due to gravitation.

> Only another collision from a celestial body can interfer with the direction they are heading they outweigh most of the competition so distraction is rare.

Indeed, the only force massive enough to alter the orbit of a planet would be another planet, either hitting it full force, or passing closely thus altering its angular momentum.  You'd need an awful lot of this to cause a planet to reach a solar system escape trajectory, however!

And it has nothing to do with colour or photon interaction.  It's all about mass.

Answer (score 1):

> My first theory would be there dark color or no color because light does not reflect back off these giants but is absorbed.

That's nothing more than a long way of saying that they're dark.

A brown dwarf is a body that's more massive than a planet but less massive than a star. It's dark simply because it's not massive enough to sustain the same kind of nuclear fusion as our Sun, the process by which stars generate light and heat. (Some may be able to fuse deuterium or lithium.)

That just tells us that they don't glow; it doesn't say anything about how they would look in reflected light. But we don't see brown dwarfs in reflected light, because there don't happen to be any close enough to the Sun or to another nearby star.

The trajectory of any body that massive is not going to be significantly affected by light pressure or by magnetic fields, whether it's hot enough to generate its own light or not. The same is true for *much* smaller bodies, down to the size of moons or asteroids. (Some smaller bodies in our Solar System have their rotation influenced by the [Yarkovsky effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky_effect), but it's not significant for anything the size of a planet or star.)

*If* it were close enough to a star, a brown dwarf might look similar to Jupiter.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf

Comment: @TheVoid: I don't think there's anything to explain. As far as I know there's nothing unusual about the trajectories that brown dwarfs follow -- and plenty of stars and even planet-like bodies follow independent trajectories through space (though we're only just beginning to be able to detect rogue planets). Even if there were something unusual, neither light pressure nor magnetic fields would be a plausible explanation.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @TheVoid the spectrum that objects emit is based on their temperature.  The sun shines the white (it's actually not yellow but white), because of it's surface temperature.   Orange and Red stars are colder, Blue are hotter.   Brown Dwarfs are the right temperature to shine in the IR spectrum.  (not UV).

Comment: @TheVoid What do you mean by "they don't behave like planets or moon".  I don't understand that comment.    Brown Dwarfs are too massive to be a moon, so that's not possible.   There are brown dwarfs that orbit other stars, similar to planets.   It's a bit of a grey area when it stops being a planet (heavy Jupiter) and becomes a brown dwarf.

Comment: @userLTK-Thanks for your correction on my theory,But capturing these Brown Dwarfs with IR spectrum can not determine there color only there volume.Light will not reflect at all of these Brown Dwarfs and light relection is how we see color.The name Brown Dwarfs was given in the 70's to give it a color but brown is not even a color in our spectrum but they still kept the name but makes since now because there really are colorless.

Comment: @userLTK: Thank you for the corrections. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TheVoid  That's true.  There's 2 different kinds of color.  There's radiative color, which is mostly an indication of temperature and there's reflective color.   Everything with temperature radiates light, but mostly below wavelengths we can see.  People glow when viewed by infra-red goggles and metals and magma glow visibly red when hot enough.   Brown Dwarfs radiate much much much more light than they reflect (The Moon also radiates more light than it reflects, by the way, we just can't see it).   It's very hard to see reflected color for anything that far away.

Comment: @TheVoid also, Brown Dwarfs wouldn't be colorless.  That's not possible for material objects.  They would either glow visibly on their own or they would have some reflective color, which could only be seen if there was a source of light near by shining on them.    If Jupiter was out in deep space, we wouldn't be able to see what color it is.   Color is just reflected or non-absorbed light that's only apparent with a light source.   I'd guess that brown dwarfs come in a variety of pretty colors, though it might be decades before we have the tech to actually see one that way.

Comment: @userLTK-I believe they are matte black due to a layer of powderd  soot absorbing all light and electromagnetic radiation,plus extremely cold making even IR very difficult to capture.But thats just my theory on how they travel through solar systems in a linear path.

Comment: @TheVoid: I don't see how their color relates to their trajectory. As we've said, light pressure would have no significant effect on the motion of a brown dwarf.